# Dark Shadows While rendering in blender

Tags: rendering, blender, shadow

I am trying to make a model, but when I try to render the file it shows dark shadows on the couch and even on floor-wall junction. I don't know what's the issue. I would really appreciate it some would look in to my file and find the problem.
Note: While using EVEE rendering is perfect. Issue is with Cycles.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVVQN.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE62q.jpg)

I would have attached .blend file, but could not. Is there any way to share the file?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a hidden object that is overlapping your mesh and causing shadows even though it is hidden in the editor - try unhiding everything using alt+h (I think) and see if there is a plane or something.

Or you may have baked some normals in there that are inverted for whatever reason.